# How to print all the values in the structures in single attempt?

Tags: c, struct, printf

In this I will have an output of 4,5,6,25.
How to print all the members in the structure in single attempt rather than accessing single member of the structure each time.
like if i need the output for row as [4 5 6] and age as 25.
Please help!

```
#include<stdio.h>

typedef struct person
{
  int row[3];
  int age;
} PERSON;

int main()
{
  PERSON p;
  PERSON *pptr=&p;
  pptr->row[0] = 4;
  pptr->row[1] = 5;
  pptr->row[2] = 6;
  pptr->age = 25;
  printf("%d\n",pptr->row[0]);
  printf("%d\n",pptr->row[1]);
  printf("%d\n",pptr->row[2]);
  printf("%d\n",pptr->age);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is no way to print without accessing each of the members. You can write a function to help you do that, though.

Comment: You could also write an abstract function that does this for structure types by passing a pointer to the structure and a pointer to a table of the member types and offsets in the structure. But unless you really need the more abstract version I'd go with simonc's answer.

Comment: @nhahtdh: For a *non portable* solution (using GNU's `glibc`) please see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using `glibc` (GNU libc, and therefore only available when using `gcc`, and though not portbale) is it possible to define and register "new" conversion specifiers to be used with `glibc`'s implementation of the `printf` familiy of functions, that are capable of what the OP is looking for.

For more on this please read here: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Registering-New-Conversions.html#Registering-New-Conversions and here: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Defining-the-Output-Handler.html#Defining-the-Output-Handler

An example can be found here: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Printf-Extension-Example.html#Printf-Extension-Example

Comment: You should mention that this is not portable in your answer, though (since it may not be immediately obvious).

Answer (score 4):

You can use multiple format specifiers in a single `printf` statement

```
printf("[%d, %d, %d], age=%d\n",
       pptr->row[0], pptr->row[1], pptr->row[2], pptr->age);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
printf ("[%d  %d  %d]\nage: %d", pptr->row[0],pptr->row[1],pptr->row[2],pptr->age);
```

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a way  to print "at once", without accessing  each member, but you
can reduce this code a little  by using multiple specifiers. Consider creating
a function (or even  a macro) if you need to print  values of multiple structs
and this shall help reducing the amount of code.

```
void
print_person (PERSON *p)
{
    printf(
        "[%d %d %d] %d\n",
        p->row[0],
        p->row[1],
        p->row[2],
        p->age
    );
}

print_person(&my_person);
```

Using the pointer approach avoids copying  the whole structure as an argument.
But you  may prefer  to keep it  simple with these  simple structs.  The macro
approach:

```
#define PRINTP(p) printf("[%d %d %d] %d\n", p.row[0], p.row[1], p.row[2], p.age)

PRINTP(p);
```

Answer (score 0):

Within langages that let you use metaprogramming and traits, you can do that but in C there’re no way to do such a thing. The simonc answer is the solution almost everyone uses.

Answer (score 0):

C doesn't provide an automatic way to do this.

Of course, you can write your own `print_struct_person` function, but you have to write one function for every function you want to print.

If you're doing this for debugging purposes, you should try a real debugger: debuggers *can* do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
void print_at_once(PERSON *pptr)
{
  int i=0;
  for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    printf("%d\n",pptr->row[i]);
  printf("%d\n",pptr->age);
  return;
}
```